# Theoretical Physics is being closed, do we want some of their questions?

Tags: discussion, migration

[TP.SE is closing](http://meta.theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/q/245/57) and it seems that the questions/answers will be [migrated in-bulk to physics.SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1193). The site is research level, and was founded with support and participation of many of our community. Do we want to grab some of the questions and migrate them to cstheory?

In particular, I am thinking about the questions under the tags: [quantum-information](http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-information), [quant-ph](http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quant-ph), and [quantum-computing](http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-computing). (Also, maybe [quantum-foundations](http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-foundations)).

I started the [counterpart discussion on TP.SE](http://meta.theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/q/246/57). Are we interested in taking the questions in these tags in-bulk? Or should we proceed on a question-by-question basis?

---

#### Update (May 5, 2012):

[TP.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23848/theoretical-physics) is now closed, questions migrated to [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

---

#### Update (May 7, 2012):

Physics.SE moderators David Zaslavsky has kindly gone over the questions migrated from TP.SE to Physics.SE and is going to migrate the suitable ones in Quantum Computing and Information to cstheory. Please have a look [at the list](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1258/quantum-computing-questions-from-tp) and let him know if you have any suggestions about the list.

Comment: It is sad to hear it. I think question in quantum-information, quantum-computing, and computer-science (and maybe some question in quantum-foundations) would be on-topic on cstheory. I think Joe's is familiar enough with the scopes of all three sites and make decisions about migrating questions to cstheory.

Comment: @Kaveh I don't want leave the burden completely on Joe, since he probably has other important things to take care off. I did not know about the [computer-science](http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-science) tag, but it has only 4 questions: one is closed, two are tagged quantum-computing, and [the last one](http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/q/75/57) is probably a stretch to be on-topic here.

Comment: personally I will be more than happy to get these quantum computing questions onto cstheory but the final decision is [TP.SE]'s. It would be nice to hear what @Joe thinks.

Comment: I support migration, or, at least, partial migration. There is a good number of posts in TP which are very interesting from the theoretical CS point of view, under the tags already mentioned.

Comment: I am not Joe, but a vice-moderator of TP.SE. In my opinion it is perfectly fine to migrate questions here, of course if you like it. However, it is good to give some thought which tags to migrate not to split the quantum community. So the further question is if along with quantum algorithms/computing are you willing to take entanglement theory and geometry of quantum states?

Comment: @Piotr, not an expert on the topics and it would be good to have the opinion of people like Peter, Joe, Scott, and others working in QC/QI. Generally questions related topics to TCS are also welcome on cstheory, e.g. there has been questions which are more pure math (e.g. probability theory) and it seems to me that users are fine with them, so I think having them on csthoery will also be fine.

Comment: Since you folks are considering this, I'll mention that we'll be having a [chat session](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1205/chat-session-on-merging-sites) to discuss how best to absorb TP.SE questions on Physics. If at least a couple of representatives from this site could attend, we could definitely discuss how to sort out TP.SE questions between your site and ours.

Comment: @Artem, can you attend the chat discussion of TP.SE?

Comment: @Kaveh I am moving apartments tomorrow, so there is a lot of cleaning and carrying to be done, but I will try to make it. It would be nice if a mod from our site could come, too. Also, I don't really have a good take on phys.SE so I might not be a good choice of representative. Joe would be an ideal person to have, but I think it is 5 in the morning for him during that chat, so I doubt he'd make it.

Comment: @Artem, I see. It would prefer if someone who is expert on quantum computing attended. I am also not sure I will be able to attend.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate... well, I am in the Physics chat room a lot so if anyone wants to pop in to discuss the migration even outside of the chat session, that would be great as well. We also have some meta posts about it that you are of course welcome to contribute to, if there is anything relevant to be said.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I will try to attend, but just in case I can't I made a [partial case for the migration](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4403283#4403283) in physics chat.

Comment: I want to apologize for not being part of this discussion. The closing of TP.SE caught me in the middle of a workshop and not really able to respond.

Comment: No problem @JoeFitzsimons, I don't think the questions were migrated here... at least I don't see any (like I searched for the Scott Aaronson's highly voted question about Wiesner quantum money that was answered by Abel Molina, and it is not here). This upsets me.

Comment: The above mentioned question [appears to be on phys.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27533/rigorous-security-proof-for-wiesners-quantum-money). I have asked for clarification in the physics chat.

Comment: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1258/quantum-computing-questions-from-tp

Comment: @Manishearth thanks for making that thread. It is both quantum-comp and quantum-info (which I think is more questions than in your post). The goal was to preserve the research-level questions, so I suspect the physics.SE quant-comp questions might be off-topic.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev: Not necessarily. We get lots of research level questions on P.SE itslef--not everyone knew that TP exists(existed). _Goes back and extracts quantum-info_

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev: THere qere 33 QI questions, so instead of hand copying them I used jQuery ^.^ . Now we just need to wait for a mod.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm fine with migrating as needed to cstheory. This makes me worried about the fate of our site :)

Comment: I think being graduated gives us a lot more leeway than the beta sites. I would be more worried about something like a CS to cstheory merger or mass migration. That could kill the community and spirit of the site without seeming as drastic as a deletion. However, I think we are safe for now :D.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev If they ask me (now a CS mod), I'll say what I've always said, which is that CSTheory and CS cater to different audiences and a merge would kill CSTheory. (Not that they would ask me.)

Comment: I think being worried a little bit about the site is not that bad after all, may help us improve things a little bit. (ps: if you look at the area51 statistic for the closed sites their situation were considerably worse, but still we are not in a shape like MO that would let us feel really good.) In any case, if that day comes for cstheory, we have a few options to consider: returning to MO, merging with CS, extending the scope to contain other research topics in CS, or moving to some other software, and each of them will have their own consequences.

Comment: ps: I feel that TP was making the Internet a better place, maybe wasn't as big as SE would like, but still it was a good high quality Q&A site for experts. It was like Microsoft Research's support for research in math/physics/etc., it does not cost them much but still has its own benefits.

Comment: I'm fine with migrating too -- I upvoted this in lieu of posting a redundant answer.

Answer (score 6):

I think Theoretical CS could truly benefit from a closer interaction with Theoretical Physics.  Acquiring the TP.SE questions might make a small contribution towards that.  I support the idea.

Answer (score 2):

[The meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/what-do-you-need-to-know-about-the-upcoming-mass-migration) on Physics.SE about the migration from TP.SE.

If you are familiar with quantum computing/information please have a look at the questions with relevant tags on [TP.SE](httP://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com) and flag them for migration to cstheory.

Comment: Problem, there is a limit of 10 moderator-flags per day. It is not much for all the questions that are interesting.

Comment: Well, it seems that nothing was really migrated here from TP.SE even after our discussion unless someone specifically flagged it. That is kind of upsetting.

Comment: @Artem, the moderators on TP.SE had to manually migrate them: Joe, Moshe, Piotr. It seems that they were busy with other stuff. I guess we can still ask the moderators on Physics.SE to migrate those questions to here from Physics.SE.

Comment: @Kaveh: [We're working on it](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1258/quantum-computing-questions-from-tp) (I'm not a mod, though, so I can't do much)

Comment: I've gone through the list of questions in the question Manishearth jus linked and tried to break them down by topic and/or level to identify which ones should be migrated. Let us know if you disagree on the breakdown, and then I can migrate the ones that should be migrated once everything is worked out.

Comment: @David, thank you.